# Не работают кнопки в уведомлении, как исправить?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Я делаю приложение - мессенджер. Когда я совершаю звонок через мессенджер появляется уведомление о звонке, это уведомление я сделал кастомное - добавил 2 кнопки(ответить сбросить) и имя пользователя который звонит. Когда уведомление отображается на некоторых устройствах кнопки работают , а на некоторых нет. При нажатии на кнопку срабатывает Ресивер, код ресивера я думаю не обязательно показывать так как в нем происходят действия после нажатия (эти действия работают и проверены на других устройствах ). В основном такая проблема встречается на Samsung , создается ощущение что приложение не подхватывает id кнопок.

Вот мой код layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/rl"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#F0F0F0"
  android:minWidth="25px"
  android:minHeight="25px">
    
   <refractored.controls.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/kot"
  
    />
          <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Имя пользователя"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_material"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="25px"
    android:maxWidth="25px"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    
    
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/MyTime"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Исходящий вызов"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_material"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btncall"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton1"
    />
  
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnendcallCenter"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"    
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/endbutton"
    />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnendcall"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/endbutton"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

код создания уведомления

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using Corporate_messenger.Service;
using Corporate_messenger.Service.Notification;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AndroidApp = Android.App.Application;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Corporate_messenger.Droid.NotificationManager.NotificationCall))]
namespace Corporate_messenger.Droid.NotificationManager
{
    class NotificationCall
    {
        const string channelId = "Call";
        const string channelName = "Notification_Call";
        const string channelDescription = "Вызовы";

        public static string TitleKey = "Call_title";
        public static string MessageKey = "Calll_message";

        bool channelInitialized = false;
      
        int pendingIntentId = 0;

        Android.App.NotificationManager manager;

        public event EventHandler NotificationReceived;
        public static NotificationCall Instance { get; private set; }

        public NotificationCall() => Initialize();
        public void Initialize()
        {
            if (Instance == null)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
                Instance = this;
            }
        }
        public void SendNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            if (!channelInitialized)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
            }


            Show(title, message);

        }

        public void ReceiveNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            var args = new NotificationEventArgs()
            {
                Title = title,
                Message = message,
            };
            NotificationReceived?.Invoke(null, args);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
        public void Show(string title, string message)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(TcpCallActivity));
           
            Intent IntentAcceptCall = new Intent("com.companyname.corporate_messenger.Accept_Receiver");
            Intent intentCancelCall = new Intent("com.companyname.corporate_messenger.Cancel_Receiver");
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            SpecialData.UserCall = message;
            TitleKey = "init_call";
                intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, "init_call");
                // intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);

                var view = new RemoteViews("com.companyname.corporate_messenger", Resource.Layout.NotificationLayoutCall);
                view.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.title_user,  message );
          
                view.SetImageViewResource(Resource.Id.image, Resource.Drawable.kot);
                
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId++, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                PendingIntent pendingAcceptCall = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId++, IntentAcceptCall, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                PendingIntent pendingCancelCall = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId++, intentCancelCall, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            SpecialData.CallPageFlag = false;
            view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_accept_call, pendingAcceptCall);
            view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_stop_call, pendingCancelCall);

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
                   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.MyChat)
                   .SetAutoCancel(true)
                   .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                   .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
                   .SetContent(view)
                   .SetContentTitle("Incoming call")
                   .SetFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)             
                   .SetOngoing(true)
                   .SetContentText(message);

            Notification notif = notification.Build();
           
            manager.Notify(0, notif);
            SpecialData.managerCall = manager;
        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            manager = (Android.App.NotificationManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(channelName);
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Max)
                {
                    LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public,
                    Importance = NotificationImportance.Max,
                    Description = channelDescription
                };
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            channelInitialized = true;
        }

        long GetNotifyTime(DateTime notifyTime)
        {
            DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(notifyTime);
            double epochDiff = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - DateTime.MinValue).TotalSeconds;
            long utcAlarmTime = utcTime.AddSeconds(-epochDiff).Ticks / 10000;
            return utcAlarmTime; // milliseconds
        }
    }
}
```

Вот тут видно результат, кнопки не работают на samsung или huawei
[image: Уведомление]

Comment: попробуй вытащить кнопки на первый план. `кнопка.bringToFront()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому то будет интересно, проблема заключалось в том , что события нажатия я отслеживал через ресиверы почему то не на всех телефонах они регистрировались. В итоге я создал класс (Сервис)

```
namespace Corporate_messenger.Droid.NotificationManager.ActionNotification
{
    [Service(Exported = true)]
    class ActionAccept : IntentService
    {
        public ActionAccept()
        {
            //
        }
        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            switch (intent.Action) {

                case "accept":
                    Task.Run(() => AcceptCall());
                    break;
                case "drop":
                    Task.Run(() => DropCall());
                    break;


            }

        }

        private async Task AcceptCall()
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await UserDbService.GetUser();



                // Соеденияся 
                //  DependencyService.Get<IAudioUDPSocketCall>().ConnectionToServer();

                // отвечаем на звонок 
                SpecialData.MyWebSocket.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    type = "init_call",
                    sender_id = user.Id,
                    status = "200",
                    receiver_id = SpecialData.receiver_id,

                    call_id = SpecialData.call_id
                }));

                // Запускаем tcp

                SpecialData.CallPageFlag = true;
                Intent mycallIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(TcpCallActivity));
                mycallIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(mycallIntent);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally{
                SpecialData.managerCall.Cancel(0);
                DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().StopAudioFile();
            }
          
          


        
           
        }
        AudioService audioService = new AudioService();
        private async Task DropCall()
        {
            try
            {
                var MyUser = await UserDbService.GetUser();

                SpecialData.MyWebSocket.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { type = "close_call", status = "403", sender_id = MyUser.Id, call_id = SpecialData.call_id }));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                SpecialData.managerCall.Cancel(0);

                audioService.StopAudioFile();
            }
           
        
            
        }
    }
}
```

и при создании уведомления , я регистрировал две кнопки, привязанных к этому классу(сервису), но с разным Action, каждый раз при нажатии я попадал в этот класс, где проверял с каким Action он запустился.
Вот отрывок кода.

```
 Intent acceptIntent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(ActionAccept));
            Intent dropIntent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(ActionAccept));
            acceptIntent.SetAction("accept");
            dropIntent.SetAction("drop");

  view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_stop_call, PendingIntent.GetService(AndroidApp.Context, 0, dropIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent));
            view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_accept_call, PendingIntent.GetService(AndroidApp.Context, 0, acceptIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent));
```

Вот полный код

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Corporate_messenger.Droid.NotificationManager.NotificationCall))]
namespace Corporate_messenger.Droid.NotificationManager
{
    class NotificationCall
    {
        const string channelId = "Call";
        const string channelName = "Notification_Call";
        const string channelDescription = "Вызовы";

        public static string TitleKey = "Call_title";
        public static string MessageKey = "Calll_message";

        bool channelInitialized = false;
      
        int pendingIntentId = 0;

        Android.App.NotificationManager manager;

        public event EventHandler NotificationReceived;
        public static NotificationCall Instance { get; private set; }

        public NotificationCall() => Initialize();
        public void Initialize()
        {
            if (Instance == null)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
                Instance = this;
            }
        }
        public void SendNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            if (!channelInitialized)
            {
                CreateNotificationChannel();
            }


            Show(title, message);

        }

        public void ReceiveNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            var args = new NotificationEventArgs()
            {
                Title = title,
                Message = message,
            };
            NotificationReceived?.Invoke(null, args);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

        Android.Widget.Button BtnStartCall;
        Android.Widget.Button BtnEndCall;
     
        public void Show(string title, string message)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(TcpCallActivity));
           
            Intent IntentAcceptCall = new Intent("com.companyname.corporate_messenger.Accept_Receiver");
            Intent intentCancelCall = new Intent("com.companyname.corporate_messenger.Cancel_Receiver");

         


        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            SpecialData.UserCall = message;
            TitleKey = "init_call";
                intent.PutExtra(TitleKey, "init_call");
                // intent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);

                var view = new RemoteViews("com.companyname.corporate_messenger", Resource.Layout.NotificationLayoutCall);
            Intent acceptIntent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(ActionAccept));
            Intent dropIntent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(ActionAccept));
            acceptIntent.SetAction("accept");
            dropIntent.SetAction("drop");

                view.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.title_user,  message );
          
                view.SetImageViewResource(Resource.Id.image, Resource.Drawable.kot);
                
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId++, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
             
            SpecialData.CallPageFlag = false;
           // view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_accept_call, pendingAcceptCall);
           // view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_stop_call, pendingCancelCall);
            view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_stop_call, PendingIntent.GetService(AndroidApp.Context, 0, dropIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent));
            view.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.button_accept_call, PendingIntent.GetService(AndroidApp.Context, 0, acceptIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent));

            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
                   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.MyChat)
                   .SetAutoCancel(true)
                   .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                   .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
                   .SetContent(view)
                   .SetContentTitle("Incoming call")
                   .SetFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
                   .SetOngoing(true)
                   .SetContentText(message)
                  .SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());

            Notification notif = notification.Build();
           
            manager.Notify(0, notif);
            SpecialData.managerCall = manager;
        }

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            manager = (Android.App.NotificationManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(channelName);
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Max)
                {
                    LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public,
                    Importance = NotificationImportance.Max,
                    Description = channelDescription
                };
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            channelInitialized = true;
        }

        long GetNotifyTime(DateTime notifyTime)
        {
            DateTime utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(notifyTime);
            double epochDiff = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - DateTime.MinValue).TotalSeconds;
            long utcAlarmTime = utcTime.AddSeconds(-epochDiff).Ticks / 10000;
            return utcAlarmTime; // milliseconds
        }
    }
}
```